# Foreach and making new objects gives nulls

Tags: java

I have a piece of code:

```
public class Main {
    static String strings[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        strings = new String[10];
        for (String s : strings) {
            s= new String("test");
        }

        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Why all of the strings still contain null instead of "test"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your enhanced for statement (for-each loop) is equivalent to:

```
T[] a = strings;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    String s = a[i];
    s = new String("test");
}
```

So your problem is similiar to this case:

```
String a = null;
String b = a;
b = new String("test");
System.out.println(a); // null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    static String strings[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        strings = new String[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
            strings[i] = new String("test");
        }

        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To print "test", try this:

public class Main {
    static String strings[];

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    strings = new String[10];
    for (int i=0; i<strings.length(); i++) {       
        strings[i]= new String("test");
    }

    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

It is forbidden to make assignments for the iterated array in a For-each loop.

Comment: You can not assign in a for-each loop in java. If you don't trust me test it. char[] c1 = { 'T', 'e', 's', 't'};
for(char x: c1) x='p'; 
System.out.println(c1); It won't work. You can use Methods yes, but you can't assign new elements.

Comment: It is permitted, though it won't change the array: [It compiled in IDEONE](http://ideone.com/RF2vDK)